# How to fix "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in Python?

Tags: python, csv

###### I am trying to write a Python script that reads a CSV file and extracts specific columns based on their header names. Here's my code:

```py
import csv

def extract_columns(filename, cols):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        headers = reader.fieldnames
        indices = [headers.index(col) for col in cols]
        data = []
        for row in reader:
            data.append([row[i] for i in indices])
        return data

data = extract_columns('data.csv', ['Name', 'Age'])
print(data)
```

When I run the script, I get the following [red] error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = extract_columns('data.csv', ['Name', 'Age'])
  File "test.py", line 8, in extract_columns
    data.append([row[i] for i in indices])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can someone please help me understand what it means and how to fix it?

Note: The CSV file contains columns with the headers "Name", "Age", and others.

Comment: It means `row` is somehow a `None`. You will need to inspect the input you have to see how that came to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above,

replace

```
data.append([row[i] for i in indices])
```

with

```
data.append([row[headers[i]] for i in indices])
```